Do I need Refresh Tokens?
Recently, I have been exploring the topic of JWT and its application to authentication systems. Many articles discuss the use of Tokens and Refresh Tokens to solve the security challenge, especially in relation to access revocation. However, I question the effectiveness of short periods like 10 minutes in mitigating significant damage.
Boosting Security: The Power of Short Tokens in Authentication
In fact, for me it doesn't make sense to use it alone in most applications.
Given this, the question arises: in a system that uses JWE and blacklist for instant revocation, what is the need for refresh_tokens?
In this scenario, each token is linked to the same session_id, which allows instant revocation by adding that session_id to the blacklist. This approach forces the user to log in again to obtain new tokens with a new session_id.
Obs: On every request, your session_id would be checked against the blacklist.
Sorry if I was rude, but it's getting difficult to find concise and coherent information.

JWE and Blacklisting does not really addresses the problem of establishing the user identity and making sure that the user is authorized to use the resource which he/she is trying to access .
Refresh Tokens are the exact means to insure that the entity consuming the resource is periodically made to reach out to the server and request re-attestation of it's identity and present it back to the Client.
The time validity of the Refresh Token is a balanced tradeoff between what the entity can do during the validity of the token in case if the entity is de-authorized from accessing a particular resource or for that matter the identity is not trusted any more . The shorter the time the lesser the Risk but more traffic on the Authentication end point , so you balance them out.

How does JWE not solve the problem of establishing user identity? A JWE is an encrypted JWT that transmits user information, allowing the server to identify the user.
As for the question of “ensuring the user has periodic updates”, just check if your permissions have changed. If this occurs, your session will be added to the blacklist, preventing the user from continuing to access without re-authenticating and granting new permissions.
Your answer is not making sense

Another point, do you really think it's ideal for us to wait for the token to expire to establish new permissions? Let's say someone accidentally gave you super-permission and then removed it from you right after, but you still have a 10-minute window before you can give yourself super-permission again.

JSON Web Encryption or JWE is a standard to exchanging encrypted data using JSON and Base64. It is a JOSE (JavaScript Object Signing and Encryption) specification that allows for the encryption of a token so that only the intended recipient can read it I assume you are using both interchangeably , while technically the token can be anything but the cost of operation is what matters using JOSE will be far more resource consuming than using the JWT which provides same if not less level of security. Also for similar reasons consider using refresh tokens for sake of standardization and efficiently
